# Theming on a collection form in SF2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Is it possible to customize the widget of a **specific** collection in a Symfony 2 Form ?

I saw this block in the default theme :

```
{% block collection_widget -%}
    {% if prototype is defined %}
        {%- set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype': form_row(prototype) }) -%}
    {% endif %}
    {{- block('form_widget') -}}
{%- endblock collection_widget %}
```

But I **dont** want to override this widget for **all** collections, just for one specific collection.

Here is the declaration of my collection :

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('photos', 'collection', [
        'type' => 'photo',
        'allow_add' => true,
    ])->setData($photosValues)
);
```

Is there a way to do something like this ?

```
{% block collection_photo_widget -%}
    Here my HTML for my photo collection
{%- endblock collection_widget %}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the right block name, go to `profiler > forms > {your form} > {your collection field} > view variables`

youll see a key there: `"unique_block_prefix"`

this is the name of your block to edit the whole collection widget, you should add _widget to the block name to go deeper

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('photos', 'collection', [
        'type' => 'photo',
        'allow_add' => true,
        'attr' => array('class'=>'myCSSClassName'),            
    ])->setData($photosValues)
);
```

No need to touch the core system